# Pull an item from a mongoDB array using Jessengers/Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I am trying to remove an element in a nested array inside mongo in my laravel project. I tried many ways to do it but after checking nothing was changed in my array.

I tried multiple way with no luck

```
        $removeItem = Carts::query()
        ->where('userUID', '=', $user->UID)
        ->where('cart', '=', 'default')
        ->where('items.item', '=', $item['item'])
        ->pull(
            'items',
            'items.$',
        );
```

i tried this as well:

```
        $removeItem = Carts::query()
        ->where('userUID', '=', $user->UID)
        ->where('cart', '=', 'default')
        ->where('items.item', '=', $item['item'])
            ->pull(
                'items',
                [
                    'item' => 'items.$.item',
                    'location' => 'items.$.location',
                    'price' => 'items.$.price',
                    'quantity' => 'items.$.quantity',
                    'status' => 'items.$.status',
                    'added_on' => 'items.$.added_on',
                    'updated_on' => 'items.$.updated_on',
                    'deleted_on' => 'items.$.deleted_on',
                ]
            );
```

[image: my document in mongo]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding the variable name to it and also because i am removing an index, going in reverse like so:

```
                  for ($i=count($userCartBis['items']) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
            
            //for now remove each element from the cart and put it in the orders section, if it's active
            if ($userCartBis['items'][$i]['status'] == 'active') {
                //this one we can process
                
                //add it to the orders table
                $updateOrder = $order
                ->push(
                    'products',
                    [
                        'location'  => $userCartBis['items'][$i]['location'],
                        'quantity'  => $userCartBis['items'][$i]['quantity'],
                        'price'     => $userCartBis['items'][$i]['price'],
                        'product'   => $userCartBis['items'][$i]['item'],
                    ]
                );
                
                //remove it from the cart table
                $removeItem = $userCart
                ->pull(
                    'items',
                    $userCartBis['items'][$i],
                );
                
            } else if ($userCartBis['items'][$i]['status'] == 'deleted') {
                //it is already deleted
                //do nothing for now
            }
            
        }
```